# Jquery plugin private data and $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am developing a JQuery plugin that stores private data in the object's data field (as was recommended in an article I found):

```
$.fn.awesomify = function (schema, data) {
    $(this).data('schema', schema);
}
```

I can then retrieve this value in a private method:

```
function rebuild() {
    var schema = $(this).data('schema');
}
```

Now the problem I have is that the value of $(this) is different when the method gets called from a different object. For example, the onclick event of an href:

```
var a = ...;
a.click(function () {
    rebuild(); // Now $(this) is the a-object
});
```

How should I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I want `$(this)` in `rebuild()` to be the object/context the plugin was created for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the value of `this` is determined at invocation time, and is set to the object which the method belongs to, or `window` if the method is not attached to an object*; `rebuild()` is not attached to an object, so `this` is `window`.

You can either pass the value of `this` in as an argument, or use the [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/[`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods;

```
rebuild.call(this);
```

or:

```
rebuild(this);

function rebuild(that) {
    var schema = $(that).data('schema');
}
```

* -> Exception is if you're in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode), where its `undefined`, but this isn't relevant here.

Comment: So I should rewrite the call to: 'var t = $(this); a.click(function () { rebuild(t); });' Not very pretty, but should work. Thanks! (Any alternative solution still very welcome)

Comment: @SaphuA that or `a.click($.proxy(function(){ rebuild(this); },this))`

Comment: Function.bind can also attach a method to an object.

Comment: But isn't the second `this` not just the a-object?

Comment: @SaphuA: Indeed, I mis-read your question and thought that's what you wanted. The general solution is to store the value of `this` in a variable, and then pass it to `rebuild` when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store "this" object to some variable and then use it from everywhere where this variable is visible

```
    var currentObj = $(this);

    function rebuild() {
       var schema = currentObj.data('schema'); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this approach, however, is that it is not plugin-friendly.

Comment: @SaphuA I agree with you. Maybe you could save it somewhere in plugin object properties